# Present date setting in android showing one month extra

Tags: android

I want to set the present date in the `Activity`(by default) and the user can configure the date by clicking on Date picker. But some devices showing one month extra, Date picker dialog also  showing  one  month extra. Can you please help me to solve this problem

```
public void setCurrentDateOnButton()
{
    Log.d(LogActivityTagNames.SCHEDULE_ACTIVITY," Entered into setCurrentDateOnButton()");
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    myear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    mday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    String month  = QuickeRideAppUtils.formatDateTime(mmonth); 
    String day = QuickeRideAppUtils.formatDateTime(mday);
    date.setText(new StringBuilder()
    .append(day).append("-").append(month).append("-")
    .append(myear).append(" "));
}
```

...

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,int selectedMonth, int selectedDay)
    {
        myear = selectedYear;
        mmonth = selectedMonth;
        mday = selectedDay;
        String month  = QuickeRideAppUtils.formatDateTime(mmonth);
        String day = QuickeRideAppUtils.formatDateTime(mday);
        date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-").append(month).append("-").append(myear).append(" "));    

    }
};
```

Comment: post code for formatDateTime() method

Comment: why you adding +1 in mmonth??

Answer (score 0):

remove +1 from this line `mmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;` just write it like

> `mmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)`

```
date.setText(new StringBuilder()
    .append(day).append("-").append(month).append("-")
    .append(myear).append(" "));
```

Comment: Some Devices adding +1 to month is working fine but in some devices it is terrible how to solve this

Comment: may be the time on those devices may be wrong(i guess)